# Error while running Python script via SSH

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I'm trying to run a Python script remotely via ssh local for a Linux machine but I'm getting an error when my script is reading a txt file, the script is running well without errors on my Python IDE.

I'm using `ssh root@ip_adress python2 < script.py` to run the script.

Part of my script where i'm reading the txt file:

```
import os
import smtplib

with open("file.txt") as fp:
     conteudo = fp.readlines()

conteudo = [linhas.strip() for linhas in conteudo]
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.txt'
```

Comment: You'll have to rewrite the question, what is "script is running well outside the terminal" supposed to mean here?  Does `file.txt` actually exist on the remote machine?

Comment: @tink The file.txt is only on my pc. Do i need to have that file on my server?

Comment: Of course.  Executing a python script via ssh does NOT give it access to files on the machine from which it was invoked, it can only see things on the machine which it's running on.

Comment: P.S.: Seeing you use `ssh root@ `  makes my stomach hurt. ;)

Comment: @tink Is there any way to make it use the file from my computer? And what should i use instead of ssh root@? I'm pretty new to this xD

Comment: Not without standing up a tunnel in the other direction from within the script or exposing the local filesystem via nfs/smb/sshfs/.. ; but that's incredibly ugly, and makes me cringe. What's the actual goal you're trying to achieve?  Maybe you need to use ansible or something like that instead of reinventing the wheel badly.

Comment: @tink I will probably transfer the file to the server and run the script normaly because making that "tunnel" looks unsafe. I think you didnt awnser the question what should i use instead of "ssh root@"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183799/discussion-between-pp-fernandes-and-tink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that the file.txt only exist on my computer, so for that to work i would need a direct connection to my server to share my filesystem with it, but that's unsafe. So i decided to transfer the file.txt to my server using `scp file.txt root@ip_adress:/path/where/the/file/is/going/to`and then i had to change the path in the "with open() as" function to the path where my file was going to. After that i was able to execute the script without errors.